# cron job - how to export data table to csv/xls file?

Tags: mysql, database, cron, export-to-csv

i'm trying to configure cron job to export automatically everyday data table from mysql DB to csv/xls.
and i'm stuck in te command field.
which command should i use ?

thank you.
mor

Comment: If you're using MySQL you can use the [MySQL Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html) to run a MySQL command. [Select into outfile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html) will produce a CSV file. No need for CRON at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old topic, but for posterity, what I've found would work in this case is to simply write the SQL in a separate file, then source the file into mysql. That way, you don't have to worry about quotes and escapes etc.

So, for example, I would have a SQL file like so, called **exportinventory.sql**

```
SELECT * 
FROM inventory INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/inventory.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

And then, from the command line:

```
mysql -u user -p database < exportinventory.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three steps to accomplish:

1. write proggy, that exports the data as you want (php, java)
2. write a bash script, which properly sets the environment and calls
   this proggy
3. insert this script in to a users crontab

you might find information for all of the three over here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
 mysql -h $DB_HOST -u $DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWORD $DB_NAME -e "$YOUR_QUERY INTO OUTFILE '$PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
```

Comment: I tried to do what you say , but it's not working. this is what i wrote:     mysql -u userXX --password=123 --database=db_xx -e SELECT 'user.q1','user.q2' FROM 'users' WHERE 'user.q2'='1' LIMIT 0, 10000 INTO OUTFILE '/csvfiles/1.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user'  LIMIT 0, 10000 INTO OUTFILE '/public_html/csvfiles/1.csv' FIELDS TERMINA' at line 1

Comment: There are errors in your query, u have to replace single quotes to back quotes.

Comment: do you mean like this: mysql -u userXX --password=123 --database=db_xx -e SELECT "user.q1","user.q2" FROM "users" WHERE "user.q2"="1" LIMIT 0, 10000 INTO OUTFILE "/csvfiles/1.csv" FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," ENCLOSED BY "\" LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"

Comment: mysql -u userXX --password=123 --database=db_xx -e SELECT \`user.q1\`,\`user.q2\` FROM users WHERE \`user.q2\`='1' LIMIT 0, 10000 INTO OUTFILE '/csvfiles/1.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

Comment: ok thank you for quick reply, now i get this error : /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: user.q1: command not found
 /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: user.q2: command not found
 /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: user.q2: command not found
 ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' FROM users WHERE ='1' LIMIT 0, 10000 INTO OUTFILE '/csvfiles/1.csv' FIELDS TERM' at line 1
 PAGER set to stdout
 PAGER set to stdout

Comment: mysql -u userXX --password=123 --database=db_xx -e "SELECT `user.q1`,`user.q2` FROM users WHERE `user.q2`='1' LIMIT 0, 10000 INTO OUTFILE '/csvfiles/1.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"